# how to make a website not responsive Magento 1.9

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, magento-1.9

I have installed a Magento 1.9 and found that it is a responsive layout whcih is really good. But I want to disable responsive feature.
Is there any way if I can disable the responsive feature in Magento 1.9.
I tried putting following values in meta tag but it didn't work. I just want website to display desktop layout on mobile devices.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=1280, maximum-scale=1" />
```

Comment: The responsiveness will be attributed to the theme, not necessarily the installation of magento. You could try installing a theme that is not responsive by default.

Comment: I want to use Magento default theme as it comes with different amazing features. I just don't want responsive layout. I just want to turn this behavior off

Comment: Responsiveness is not something you "turn off" - it is set in the stylesheet for the theme. Additionally, the features of magento are not suddenly abandoned just because you switch themes. What features are you referring to that are not available if you switch themes? Features of magento are attributed to the core and any modules installed. The core and modules are designed to work regardless of the theme you install. It's a cascading system to put it plainly. If a theme you install does not support a certain portion of the site, the default theme will fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the css...

```
body {
min-width:1280px;
}
```

Bear in mind that width is larger than most non-widescreen monitors, however.

I'd probably then remove the maximum scale from your viewport as I think that would prevent someone zooming in, thus making your site unusable on a smart phone.

I'd then try just:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1280" />
```

for the viewport.

Comment: I tried that but it is still changing it. I just want the responsive behavior to completely off